# No production of graph in R with no errors or warnings

Tags: r

I'm trying to produce a number of graphs in a pdf using R.  I get no warnings or errors, but my graphs aren't produced and I'm not using some of the packages that others were when they encountered similar issues.  My code is below.  At first I rearranged my data vectors, came up with a matrix, turned it into a data frame (I think that's where the problem has to be, but I can't find it) then I produce my graphs.

```
SWCvec<-matrix(data=c(38,30.8,33.4,27.3,23.1,34.3,16.4,11.3,
14.8,27.7,23.1,36.1,10.5,8.3,10.4,30.4,30.2,36.2,8,5.2,7.3,
27.1,19.9,28.7,6.1,2.5,5.1,20.7,18.9,31.5),ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
SWCdata<-data.frame(S1=SWCvec[,1],S2=SWCvec[,2],S3=SWCvec[,3],S4=SWCvec[,4],S5=SWCvec[,5],S6=SWCvec[,6])
SWC1<-c(SWCdata$S1,SWCdata$S2,SWCdata$S3)
SWC2<-c(SWCdata$S4,SWCdata$S5,SWCdata$S6)
Lpsivec<-matrix(data=c(-0.45,-0.5,-0.5,-0.6,-0.5,-0.65,-0.8,-0.85,-0.85,-0.65,-0.5,-0.45,-1.15,-1.2,-1.1,-0.65,-0.5,-0.9,-1.25,-1.65,-1.15,-0.65,-0.55,-0.65,-1.25,-1.65,-1.4,-0.75,-0.55,-0.65),ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
Lpsidata<-data.frame(L1=Lpsivec[,1],L2=Lpsivec[,2],L3=Lpsivec[,3],L4=Lpsivec[,4],L5=Lpsivec[,5],L6=Lpsivec[,6])
Lpsi1<-c(Lpsidata$L1,Lpsidata$L2,Lpsidata$L3)
Lpsi2<-c(Lpsidata$L4,Lpsidata$L5,Lpsidata$L6)
Pnvec<-matrix(data=c(3.885,8.615,5.7,5.62,4.84,6.84,1.065,4.035,4.485,7.245,7.815,7.435,0.3795,0.655,1.325,2.985,6.425,5.63,0.473,2.125,1.335,5.62,7.455,6.48,0.386,1.329,1.17,6.6,6.125,10.3),ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
Pndata<-data.frame(P1=Pnvec[,1],P2=Pnvec[,2],P3=Pnvec[,3],P4=Pnvec[,4],P5=Pnvec[,5],P6=Pnvec[,6])
Pn1<-c(Pndata$P1,Pndata$P2,Pndata$P3)
Pn2<-c(Pndata$P4,Pndata$P5,Pndata$P6)
GWvec<-matrix(data=c(0.038,0.122,0.054,0.06,0.062,0.093,0.00575,0.0366,0.03355,0.099,0.14095,0.135,0.00755,0.01485,0.0138,0.046,0.079,0.07055,0.00705,0.0164,0.01455,0.08555,0.21,0.1455,0.00815,0.01545,0.0141,0.1285,0.245,0.261),ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
GWdata<-data.frame(G1=GWvec[,1],G2=GWvec[,2],G3=GWvec[,3],G4=GWvec[,4],G5=GWvec[,5],G6=GWvec[,6])
GW1<-c(GWdata$G1,GWdata$G2,GWdata$G3)
GW2<-c(GWdata$G4,GWdata$G5,GWdata$G6)
WUEvec<-matrix(data=c(102.2368421,70.6147541,105.5555556,93.66666667,78.06451613,73.5483871,185.2173913,110.2459016,133.681073,73.18181818,55.44519333,55.07407407,50.26490066,44.10774411,96.01449275,64.89130435,81.32911392,79.80155918,67.09219858,129.5731707,91.75257732,65.69257744,35.5,44.53608247,47.36196319,86.01941748,82.9787234,51.3618677,25,39.46360153),ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
WUEdata<-data.frame(W1=WUEvec[,1],W2=WUEvec[,2],W3=WUEvec[,3],W4=WUEvec[,4],W5=WUEvec[,5],W6=WUEvec[,6])
WUE1<-c(WUEdata$W1,WUEdata$W2,WUEdata$W3)
WUE2<-c(WUEdata$W4,WUEdata$W5,WUEdata$W6)
A<-c(Lpsi1, Lpsi2, SWC1, SWC2, Pn1, Pn2, GW1, GW2, WUE1, WUE2)
Amat<-matrix(data=A,nrow=30,byrow=FALSE)
Amat
V0<-c(rep(0, each=15))
V1<-c(rep(1, each=15))
V2<-c(V0,V1)
Y<-cbind(Amat,V2)
Xdata<-data.frame(Lpsi=Y[,1], SWC=Y[,2], Pn=Y[,3], GW=Y[,4], WUE=Y[,5], Treatment=Y[,6])
pdf("P2Graph.pdf")
plot(Xdata$SWC, Xdata$Lpsi, col=Xdata$Treatment+1, pch=Xdata$Treatment+3,main="Leaf Water Potential versus Soil Water Content",xlab='Soil Water Content', ylab='Leaf Water Potential')
plot(Xdata$SWC, Xdata$Pn, col=Xdata$Treatment+1, pch=Xdata$Treatment+3,main="Net Photosynthetic Rate versus Soil Water Content",xlab='Soil Water Content', ylab='Net Photosynthetic Rate')
plot(Xdata$SWC, Xdata$GW, col=Xdata$Treatment+1, pch=Xdata$Treatment+3,main="Stomatal Conductance versus Soil Water Content",xlab='Soil Water Content', ylab='Stomatal Conductance')
plot(Xdata$SWC, Xdata$WUE, col=Xdata$Treatment+1, pch=Xdata$Treatment+3,main="Instantaneous Water Use Efficiency versus Soil Water Content",xlab='Soil Water Content', ylab='Instantaneous Water Use Efficiency')
plot(Xdata$Lpsi, Xdata$Pn, col=Xdata$Treatment+1, pch=Xdata$Treatment+3,main="Net Photosynthetic Rate versus Leaf Water Potential",xlab='Leaf Water Potential', ylab='Net Photosynthetic Rate')
plot(Xdata$Lpsi, Xdata$GW, col=Xdata$Treatment+1, pch=Xdata$Treatment+3,main="Stomatal Conductance versus Leaf Water Potential",xlab='Leaf Water Potential', ylab='Stomatal Conductance')
plot(Xdata$GW, Xdata$Pn, col=Xdata$Treatment+1, pch=Xdata$Treatment+3,main="Net Photosynthetic Rate versus Stomatal Conductance",xlab='Stomatal Conductance', ylab='Net Photosynthetic Rate')
plot(Xdata$Lpsi, Xdata$WUE, col=Xdata$Treatment+1, pch=Xdata$Treatment+3,main="Intrinsic Water Use Efficiency versus Leaf Water Potential",xlab='Leaf Water Potential', ylab='Intrinsic Water Use Efficiency')
pdf()
```

Comment: try this: change your last statement `pdf()` by `dev.off()`.

Comment: Is this really a [_minimal_ reproducible example](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing your plot-to-device calls. The way to terminate a `pdf` call is with `dev.off()`, not `pdf()` with no arguments. (yeah, I know it's not consistent with sink(file) ... sink() but I didn't write the language. I also didn't write the `?Devices` page which I think should have been more complete about closing device calls. See:

```
 ?Devices
 ?dev.off()
```